# Application exit with status 45

Tags: ios, xcode

I have jailbroken device ios version 5.0.1

When ever I try to debug my app on device the app exit with status 45.
I am using xcode 3.2.5 to debug. Is it not possible to debug on device os version higher than xcode sdk?

By the way here is the console log I got

```
unable to read unknown load command 0x25
unable to read unknown load command 0x26
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-414-49
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 7171]
[Switching to thread 7171]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
continue

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't possible, this is most likely due to Xcode 3 not knowing how to handle your version of iOS. You'll either have to find a way to downgrade your device, or upgrade to Xcode 4.2 which supports iOS 5.0.1.